# How to run the same script multiple times with different input and output files?

Tags: python

I am doing my data analysis using the python script, each set of analysis take about 2-3 hours. Is it possible to write a script that can run another file one after the other?
ex. I specified the analysis files I want to be run in the main file, and I simply run the main file and it will automatically run the analysis files?

Or, is there any editor can do that?

From a beginner in python and programming.

Below is the script I want to run multiple time (after changing the infile and outfile location)

---

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
import csv
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.stats import t
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#basic information --set up variable
#method infodisgunsh
denatureMethod="CD" # choose 'CD' for chemical denature, 'HD' for heat denature
CD_xaxis_FinalGdmClConcentration_value=[0,0.43,0.87,1.3,1.74,2.17,2.61,3.04,3.48]
CD_conc_upbound=3.48
CD_conc_lowbound=0
CD_conc_range=CD_conc_upbound-CD_conc_lowbound
HD_xasis_normalizedTemp_value=[0,0.129277567,0.224334601,0.338403042,0.429657795,0.539923954,0.646387833,0.775665399,0.882129278,1]
HD_Temp_upbound=63
HD_Temp_lowbound=36.7
HD_temp_range=HD_Temp_upbound-HD_Temp_lowbound
CI_cutoff=0.3

#run info
descriptionOfTheRun="F_diet"# what ever desciption can distinguish
numOfReplicate="1" # number of replicate used to generate 1 fit
plotColor="2"#1=blue,2=organe,3=purple,4=brown

#file selection
infile_locationAndName="G:\BYU OneDrive_G\OneDrive - BYU Office 365\BYU\===Price lab===\Coding\\1023-CD+HD +multi rep\\1023-input_python_test.csv"
outfile_locationAndName="G:\BYU OneDrive_G\OneDrive - BYU Office 365\BYU\===Price lab===\Coding\\1023-CD+HD +multi rep\\1026-CDtest_output.csv"
outImage_location="G:\BYU OneDrive_G\OneDrive - BYU Office 365\BYU\===Price lab===\Coding\\1023-CD+HD +multi rep\\"

#info for each peptide from infile
rowLoc=0
IDLoc=1
NameLoc=2
PeptideLoc=3
ReporterLoc=4

#rep1 info
rep1_notebookCode="LL1091" #the notebook code of the run
rep1_numPtsLocation=5# type in the number get from excel column to python raw translator
rep1_Statrt=6 # type in the number get from excel column to python raw translator
rep1_End=14# type in the number get from excel column to python raw translator

"""#rep2 info
rep2_notebookCode="LL1191" #the notebook code of the run
rep2_numPtsLocation=16# type in the number get from excel column to python raw translator
rep2_Statrt=17 # type in the number get from excel column to python raw translator
rep2_End=26# type in the number get from excel column to python raw translator

#rep3_info
rep3_notebookCode="LL1101" #the notebook code of the run
rep3_numPtsLocation=1# type in the number get from excel column to python raw translator
rep3_Statrt=5 # type in the number get from excel column to python raw translator
rep3_End=6# type in the number get from excel column to python raw translator"""

"""#rep4_info
rep4_notebookCode="LL1101" #the notebook code of the run
rep4_numPtsLocation=1# type in the number get from excel column to python raw translator
rep4_Statrt=5 # type in the number get from excel column to python raw translator
rep4_End=6# type in the number get from excel column to python raw translator"""


#plot color Code, usually don't need to change
color1_dataAndFit="#1f77b4"#blue
color1_Chalf="#aec7e8"
color1_CI="#c6dbef"


color2_dataAndFit="#ff7f0e"#orgnae
color2_Chalf="#ffbb78"
color2_CI="#fdd0a2"

color3_dataAndFit="#5254a3"#purple
color3_Chalf="#9e9ac8"
color3_CI="#dadaeb"

color4_dataAndFit="#8c6d31"#brown
color4_Chalf="#e7ba52"
color4_CI="#e7cb94"




def sigmoid(x,B,A,Chalf, b):#the fitting equation
    y =B+((A-B)/(1+np.exp((-1/b)*(Chalf-x))))
    return y

infile=open(infile_locationAndName,"r")#"r"=reading mode
reader=csv.reader(infile)#create reader object
header=next(reader)





#base on replication numbers
if numOfReplicate=="1":
    xdata1=[]
    finalData=[]
    for i in range(rep1_Statrt,rep1_End+1):#5 is the data start, 15 is the end of data+1
        flow=float(header[i])#making the input value to number
        xdata1.append(flow)
    for row in reader:
        # input y value
        ydata1=[]
        for i in range(rep1_Statrt,rep1_End+1):# it means row[5] to row[15]
            flow=float(row[i])#making the input value to number
            ydata1.append(flow)

        #baisc information input
        title=row[rowLoc]
        ID=row[IDLoc]
        proteinName=row[NameLoc]
        Peptide=row[PeptideLoc]
        numOfReporter=row[ReporterLoc]
        numOf_rep1_pts=row[rep1_numPtsLocation]

        #baisc information ouput
        tempRow=[title]#[0]
        tempRow.append(ID)#[1]
        tempRow.append(proteinName)#[2]
        tempRow.append(Peptide)#[3]
        tempRow.append(numOfReporter)#[4]
        tempRow.append(numOf_rep1_pts)#[5]

        try:#if statment, when it is not error
            #normalized the data
            normalized_ydata1=[]
            normalized_xdata1=[]

            #normalizing rep1 dataset
            if denatureMethod=="CD":#first point is 0, last point is 1
                for element in ydata1: # read from the begining, find first data !=0, make it A
                    if element !=0:
                        A=element# set 0
                        break
                for element in reversed(ydata1): #read from the end, find first data !=0, make it B
                    if element !=0:
                        B=element#set 1
                        #print ("A",A)
                        break
                for i in range(len(ydata1)):
                    if ydata1[i] !=0:
                        element=(ydata1[i]-A)/(B-A) #3 for each data !=0, normalized_ydata=(data-A)/(B-A)
                        normalized_ydata1.append(element)
                        normalized_xdata1.append(xdata1[i]) #4 for each normalized_ydata, find the xdata, make it normalized_xdata
                    else:
                        normalized_ydata1.append("error")
                        normalized_xdata1.append(xdata1[i])

            if denatureMethod=="HD":#first point is 1, last point is 0
                for element in ydata1: #1 read from the begining, find first data !=0, make it B
                    if element !=0:
                        B=element# set 1
                        break
                for element in reversed(ydata1): #2 read from the end, find first data !=0, make it A
                    if element !=0:
                        A=element#set 0
                        break
                for i in range(len(ydata1)):
                    if ydata1[i] !=0:
                        element=(ydata1[i]-A)/(B-A) #3 for each data !=0, normalized_ydata=(data-A)/(B-A)
                        normalized_ydata1.append(element)
                        normalized_xdata1.append(xdata1[i]) #4 for each normalized_ydata, find the xdata, make it normalized_xdata
                    else:
                        normalized_ydata1.append("error")
                        normalized_xdata1.append(xdata1[i])

            #Set data set for fit and plot
            xplot1=[]
            yplot1=[]

            for i in range (len(normalized_ydata1)):
                if normalized_ydata1[i]!="error":
                    yplot1.append(normalized_ydata1[i])
                    xplot1.append(normalized_xdata1[i])

            #fit Rep1 to s curve
            AL_fit_result_output=[]
            popt1, pcov1 = curve_fit(sigmoid, xplot1, yplot1)
            AL_fit_result_output.extend(popt1)#extend merge two list to one big list
                                                #popt has all the parameter (variable) in regression equation (x,B, A, Chalf, b)
                                                                                                        #row [-, 0, 1, 2,    3] in  AL_fit_result_output
            if denatureMethod=="CD":
                x1 = np.linspace(0, 4, 50)
            if denatureMethod=="HD":
                x1 = np.linspace(0, 1.2, 50)
            y1= sigmoid(x1, *popt1)# *popt split the two variable
            AL_Chalf=AL_fit_result_output[2]
            AL_b=AL_fit_result_output[3]

            #calculate AL confidence interval
            numOfPoint_AL_repA=float(numOf_rep1_pts)
            sumPoints_AL=numOfPoint_AL_repA
            tempRow.append(sumPoints_AL)#[6]
            AL_Standard_error=np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov1))
            AL_fit_result_output.extend(AL_Standard_error)#[4,5,6,7]=[Berror, Aerror, Chalferror, berror]
            AL_ConfidenceInterval_chalf=t.ppf(.975, (sumPoints_AL-1))* AL_fit_result_output[6]/np.sqrt(sumPoints_AL)
            AL_fit_result_output.append(AL_ConfidenceInterval_chalf)#[8]
            if denatureMethod=="CD":
                CI_ratioTOrange=AL_ConfidenceInterval_chalf/CD_conc_range
                AL_fit_result_output.append(CI_ratioTOrange)#[9]
            if denatureMethod=="HD":
                CI_ratioTOrange=AL_ConfidenceInterval_chalf/HD_temp_range
                AL_fit_result_output.append(CI_ratioTOrange)#[9]
            AL_CI_Chalf_lowbound=AL_Chalf-AL_fit_result_output[8]
            AL_CI_Chalf_upbound=AL_Chalf+AL_fit_result_output[8]
            AL_fit_result_output.append(AL_CI_Chalf_lowbound)#[10]
            AL_fit_result_output.append(AL_CI_Chalf_upbound)#[11]
            AL_ConfidenceInterval_b=t.ppf(.975, (sumPoints_AL-1))* AL_fit_result_output[7]/np.sqrt(sumPoints_AL)
            AL_fit_result_output.append(AL_ConfidenceInterval_b)#[12]
            AL_CI_b_lowbound=AL_b-AL_fit_result_output[12]
            AL_CI_b_upbound=AL_b+AL_fit_result_output[12]
            AL_fit_result_output.append(AL_CI_b_lowbound)#[13]
            AL_fit_result_output.append(AL_CI_b_upbound)#[14]

            #compute AL r squared
            residuals=(yplot1)-sigmoid((xplot1),*popt1)
            ss_res=np.sum(residuals**2)
            ss_tot=np.sum(((yplot1)-np.mean(yplot1))**2)
            r_squared1=1-(ss_res/ss_tot)
            AL_fit_result_output.append(r_squared1)#[15]; append add something to the list
            if denatureMethod=="HD":
                Chalf1_temp=(AL_Chalf*HD_temp_range)+HD_Temp_lowbound
                AL_fit_result_output.append(Chalf1_temp)#[16]
            if denatureMethod=="CD":
                Chalf1_normalized=AL_Chalf/CD_conc_range
                AL_fit_result_output.append(Chalf1_normalized)#[16]



            tempRow.extend(AL_fit_result_output)
            tempRow.extend(normalized_ydata1)


            #generate the figure
            if CI_ratioTOrange<CI_cutoff:
                graphName=descriptionOfTheRun+"_"+"row#"+title+" (has CI)"+"\n"+ID +"||"+ proteinName+"\n"+Peptide
            else:
                graphName=descriptionOfTheRun+"_"+"row#"+title+"\n"+ID +"||"+ proteinName+"\n"+Peptide

            #plot color
            if plotColor=="1":#choose from blue, orange, purple, brown
                plt.plot(xplot1, yplot1,color=color1_dataAndFit,ls=':',marker='o',label='rep1_'+rep1_notebookCode)
                #plt.plot(xplot2, yplot2,color=color1_dataAndFit,ls=':',marker='^',label='AL_1057')
                pylab.plot(x1,y1,color1_dataAndFit, label='fit')
                pylab.axvline(AL_Chalf,color=color1_Chalf,ls='-',label='C1/2')#chalf
                if CI_ratioTOrange<CI_cutoff:
                    plt.axvspan((AL_Chalf-AL_fit_result_output[8]), (AL_Chalf+AL_fit_result_output[8]),color=color1_CI)#CI
            if plotColor=="2":#choose from blue, orange, purple, brown
                plt.plot(xplot1, yplot1,color=color2_dataAndFit,ls=':',marker='o',label='rep1_'+rep1_notebookCode)
                #plt.plot(xplot2, yplot2,color=color2_dataAndFit,ls=':',marker='^',label='AL_1057')
                pylab.plot(x1,y1,color2_dataAndFit, label='fit')
                pylab.axvline(AL_Chalf,color=color2_Chalf,ls='-',label='C1/2')#chalf
                if CI_ratioTOrange<CI_cutoff:
                    plt.axvspan((AL_Chalf-AL_fit_result_output[8]), (AL_Chalf+AL_fit_result_output[8]),color=color2_CI)#CI
            if plotColor=="3":#choose from blue, orange, purple, brown
                plt.plot(xplot1, yplot1,color=color3_dataAndFit,ls=':',marker='o',label='rep1_'+rep1_notebookCode)
                #plt.plot(xplot2, yplot2,color=color3_dataAndFit,ls=':',marker='^',label='AL_1057')
                pylab.plot(x1,y1,color3_dataAndFit, label='fit')
                pylab.axvline(AL_Chalf,color=color3_Chalf,ls='-',label='C1/2')#chalf
                if CI_ratioTOrange<CI_cutoff:
                    plt.axvspan((AL_Chalf-AL_fit_result_output[8]), (AL_Chalf+AL_fit_result_output[8]),color=color3_CI)#CI
            if plotColor=="4":#choose from blue, orange, purple, brown
                plt.plot(xplot1, yplot1,color=color4_dataAndFit,ls=':',marker='o',label='rep1_'+rep1_notebookCode)
                #plt.plot(xplot2, yplot2,color=color4_dataAndFit,ls=':',marker='^',label='AL_1057')
                pylab.plot(x1,y1,color4_dataAndFit, label='fit')
                pylab.axvline(AL_Chalf,color=color4_Chalf,ls='-',label='C1/2')#chalf
                if CI_ratioTOrange<CI_cutoff:
                    plt.axvspan((AL_Chalf-AL_fit_result_output[8]), (AL_Chalf+AL_fit_result_output[8]),color=color4_CI)#CI

            #plot label
            if denatureMethod=="CD":
                pylab.xlabel('denaturant concentration')
                pylab.ylabel('% labeled')
            if denatureMethod=="HD":
                pylab.xlabel('normalized temperature')
                pylab.ylabel('% soluble')
            #pylab.ylim(0.3, 2.2)
            pylab.legend(loc='best')
            pylab.title(graphName,fontsize=10)
            pylab.savefig(outImage_location+title+"_"+proteinName+".jpg")
            pylab.clf()#clearfig, start a new piece , make sure do it before or after a set of instruction

        except :#define the error
            print (title)

        finalData.append(tempRow)

    #output the data file
    outfile=open(outfile_locationAndName,"w",newline="")
    writer=csv.writer(outfile)#create write object
    newheader=["row","protein ID","ProteinNAme","Peptide","numOfReporter","numOf_rep1_pts","sumPoints"]
    newheader_AL_fitOutPut_CD=["B","A","Chalf","b","B_err","A_err","Chalf_err","b_err","CI_Chalf","CIratioTOrange","CI_Chalf_low","CI_Chalf_up","CI_b","CI_b_low","CI_b_up","r_square","Chalf_normalized"]
    newheader_AL_fitOutPut_HD=["B","A","Chalf","b","B_err","A_err","Chalf_err","b_err","CI_Chalf","CIratioTOrange","CI_Chalf_low","CI_Chalf_up","CI_b","CI_b_low","CI_b_up","r_square","Chalf_temp"]
    if denatureMethod=="CD":
        newheader.extend(newheader_AL_fitOutPut_CD)
        normalized_header1=CD_xaxis_FinalGdmClConcentration_value
        newheader.extend(normalized_header1)
    if denatureMethod=="HD":
        newheader.extend(newheader_AL_fitOutPut_HD)
        normalized_header1=HD_xasis_normalizedTemp_value
        newheader.extend(normalized_header1)

    writer.writerow(newheader)
    for addvariable in finalData:
        writer.writerow(addvariable)
    outfile.close()
    infile.close()
```

Comment: Hi, yes this is exactly the sort of thing that python and programming is good for. But how to make this work depends on the script you are running. Can you include the script you are running in your question?

Comment: It is highly likely that what you want is possible but we need more information to help. How are you currently starting your script?

Comment: thank you for the advice, I just updated my post with my code.

Answer (score 2):

To do it, you could use the following "driver" script, but to use it you'll also need to modify the data analysis script so it accepts the input and output file names as command-line arguments.

Also note how the file location and names have had an `r` prefix added to them. This is because Windows uses the backslash `\` character as a path component separator character, but it has special meaning when used in Python string literals. The prefix prevents that interpretation and treats them as normal characters—what's wanted in this case.

Alternately, you could also have changed them all to forward slashes `/` characters which wouldn't require adding the `r` prefix because they also work as path separators in Python scripts.

Anyway, here's the driver script (which you could execute from an editor if it supports the execution of Python scripts):

```
import subprocess
import sys

analysis_script = 'data_analysis.py'

file_list = [
    [r"G:\BYU OneDrive_G\OneDrive - BYU Office 365\BYU\===Price lab===\Coding\\1023-CD+HD +multi rep\\1023-input_python_test.csv",
     r"G:\BYU OneDrive_G\OneDrive - BYU Office 365\BYU\===Price lab===\Coding\\1023-CD+HD +multi rep\\1026-CDtest_output.csv"
    ],
    [r"G:\BYU OneDrive_G\OneDrive - BYU Office 365\BYU\===Price lab===\Coding\\1023-CD+HD +multi rep\\1036-input_python_test.csv",
     r"G:\BYU OneDrive_G\OneDrive - BYU Office 365\BYU\===Price lab===\Coding\\1023-CD+HD +multi rep\\1042-CDtest_output.csv"
    ],
    # etc ...
]

for infile, outfile in file_list:
    # Note: It's important to put double quotes around everything in case they
    # have embedded space characters in them.
    command = '"%s" "%s" "%s" "%s"' % (sys.executable,      # command
                                       analysis_script,     # argv[0]
                                       infile,              # argv[1]
                                       outfile)             # argv[2]
    subprocess.Popen(command)  # Run script and pass it the files.

print('Done')
```

For it to work you'll also need to have something like the following near the beginning of the data analysis script and remove the hard-coded input and output files names it's currently using.

Here's an example of what needs to be added at the beginning:

```
import sys

try:
    infile_locationAndName = sys.argv[1]
    outfile_locationAndName =  sys.argv[2]
except IndexError:
    print('ERROR: wrong number of command-line arguments passed')
    print('  Usage: "{}" <input file name> <output file name>'.format(
            os.path.basename(__file__)))
    raise RuntimeError('Missing two required command-line arguments')

# Rest of the (modified) data analysis script ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.system(python3 <file> <arg1> <arg2> <arg3>)
```

The first script will not close until the last script has finished executing, but this should not be a problem, because it is single threaded.

Comment: Maybe instead of putting it at the bottom of each script, put it in the mentioned `main` file. That should be simpler.

Comment: No problem. Just sayin', the argument to `os.system` should be a string. So like `os.system("python3 <file> <arg1> <arg2> <arg3>")`

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux or mac you can use a bash script. e.g inside a `.sh` file:

```
python script1.py
python script2.py
...
```

then run on a terminal `bash yourfile.sh`